# Variable printing issue

Tags: java

Why its imprinting all the values when its suppose to be only 5 of 20.

I try to evaluate whatever its on the value money, and then I calculate.

```
    int stamp50 = 0;
    int stamp20 = 0;
    int stamp1 = 0;
    int total = 0;

    int money = 100;

    if (money > 50) {
        total = money % 50;
        stamp50 = money / 50;

        total = money % 20;
        stamp20 = money / 20;

        total = money % 1;
        stamp1 = money / 1;

    } else if (money >= 20 && money <= 50) {
        total = money % 20;
        stamp20 = money / 20;

        total = money % 1;
        stamp1 = money / 1;
    } else if (money < 20) {
        total = money % 1;
        stamp1 = money / 1;
    }

    System.out.println(" De 50 " + stamp50 + " De 20 " + stamp20 + " De 1 " + stamp1);
```

Comment: What type of error You are getting you tell the error It may helpful to find out the bug...

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: "De 50 0 De 20 1 De 1 20"

whent its only suppose to get

"De 50 0 De 20 5 de 1 0

Comment: But would not be "De 50 2 De 20 5 De 1 100"?

Answer (score 0):

So you said above, the output you are getting is: `"De 50 0 De 20 1 De 1 20"` and the output you want to get is `"De 50 0 De 20 5 de 1 0"`

```
    total = money % 50;
    stamp50 = money / 50;

    total = money % 20;
    stamp20 = money / 20;

    total = money % 1;
    stamp1 = money / 1;
```

The output should be, according to your program is:

`"De 50 2 De 20 5 de 1 100"`

I think, according to the output you expect, you're doing the wrong calculations for

`stamp50 = money / 50;`
`stamp1 = money / 1;`

Maybe they should be `%` signs and not `/`.  Or maybe you're not using the correct variables?

`stamp50 = total / 50;`
`stamp1 = total / 1;`

Maybe you could explain what it is exactly you're trying to do and we could help you more.

Comment: The way it should work.

stamp1 = stamps of a dollars
stamp20 = stamps of twenty dollars
stamp50 = stamps of fifty dollars

if money is more than 50. I then see how many stamps of 50 dollars they can buy, and then how many of twenty, and then how many of a dollar.

same with the rest. Then at the end I just print the values of the variables

Comment: Then should `"De 50 2 De 20 5 de 1 100"` not be the correct output?  `2 $50 for $100, 5 $20 for $100 and 100 $1 for $100?`

Comment: No, the correct output should be 2 %50 for $100, 0 $20 etc.. I want to pay the maximum possible